# Cypress: Should new cy.intercept() method mock responses for requests sent not from browser, but using cy.request() method?

Tags: cypress

I am creating an end to end test, where some specific data should be retrieved via API using

```
cy.request({
      method: "POST",
      url: ...,
      headers: {
        "X-Auth-Token": ...,
      },
      body: {
        target_url: ...,
      },
    });
```

For now my API can't send me the data, so while it is being fixed I had an idea to mock this request using

```
  cy.intercept(
    {
      method: "POST",
      url: ...,
    },
    {
      body: {
        target_url:
          ...,
      },
    }
```

So I can set all necessary data into the body to stub response

But it just does not work for me now, I read carefully all the docs, but still I can't understand -  cy.intercept does not work for cy.request or I just made an error somewhere?

Thank you for any information =)